# How to split list values in column into rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
id    val
1    ["hi", "there"]
2    ["lovely"]
```

How could I split list values in column into rows to get:

```
id       val
1         hi 
1      there
2     lovely
```

I have tried `.melt()` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This is what pandas' [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) is here for!

```
df = df.explode('val')
```

Returns:

```
id       val
1         hi 
1      there
2     lovely
```